# Notepad ++ Find all lines containing xxxxxx/Reports/reportname.pdf and replace with xxxxxx/Reports/PDF/reportname.pdf

Tags: regex, notepad++

[Screenshot of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNYFU.png)I have a file which contains multiple lines

```
Source Path                       Target Path

xxxx/out/reportname1.pdf         xxxx/out/Reports/reportname1.pdf
xxxx/out/reportname2.txt         xxxx/out/Reports/reportname2.txt
xxxx/out/reportname3.csv         xxxx/out/Reports/reportname2.csv
```

I would like to replace `/Reports/reportname1.pdf` to `/PDFReports/reportname1.pdf` for only PDF files.

Please suggest I tried using `/Reports/.*pdf` and I am able to find it, but unable to replace it

Comment: Find: (?<=\/)(Reports\/.+\.pdf) Replace: PDF\1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `\/Reports\/(.*?\.pdf)` and replace with `/PDFReports/$1`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use replacing with regex syntax (ctrl+H by default)

Try something like:

Find what:

```
\/Reports\/(.*\.pdf)
```

Replace with:

```
/PDFReports/$1
```

And use "regular expression" search mode.

This mechanism is called [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - braces in "Find what" are used to remember the content inside them and then this content is references later by $1.

**Note** - you might have to use "\1" instead of "$1" in case of old version of Np++

Comment: How about using `\S*` instead of `.*` ([demo why](https://regex101.com/r/aR4eG4/1))

Comment: The answer was written prior to edit of the post that added form

    column 1          column 2
    <symbols>.pdf <symbols>.pdf

And `\S` match may stop at an unwanted point, say at a filename containing a space.

Answer (score 0):

searching pattern: `([\w\_]+\.\w+)`

replace to: `Reports/$1`

output:

```
xxxx/out/Reports/reportname1.pdf
xxxx/out/Reports/reportname2.txt
xxxx/out/Reports/reportname3.csv
```

EDIT: since filenames could containt _, little upgrade.